# Dynamically update UILabel text based on compression

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

Is it possible to create a UILabel subclass that automatically updates its text based on whether it has enough space or not?  Similar to the way the label can add ellipses.

I would like to create two properties `preferredText` and `alternateText` and have the label select automatically between the two based on the amount of space it has available.  So, I could do something like `preferredText = @"Count text: 1024"; alternateText = @"1024";`.

I've looked at `intrinsicContentSize` of course, but I think that should always return a value based on `preferredText`.  I also looked at overriding `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` and `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:...` but these methods are never called during autolayout.  I also tried overriding `layoutSubviews`, but at that point the system has already decided how big it wants the label to be.  Changing the text there can result in an infinite loop.

Ideally I would like a generalized solution that I could apply to other view types as well.  For example, a custom uibutton might choose a different image if there is not sufficient space.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look at the preferred text and the size of the label, and then look at the required size for the text (easily done using `boundingRectWithSize...`) and see whether it will fit. Depending what you learn, you would then assign the preferred text or the alternate text.

(It would be better, however, to allow the label to resize itself depending on its text, which is what it wants to do automatically anyway. Or you could take advantage of the fact that a label is happy to shrink its font size if that's what it takes to make the text fit.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I understand how to calculate the size of a label.  The question is really which method or methods would be best to override so that a) the system knows that it can make the label smaller, and b)  replace the text once the size has been set.  The answer to a. would appear to be `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:...` and return the size for `alternateText` if `preferedText` doesn't fit, but that method is never called during layout.  For b., it would seem like `layoutSubviews`, but as I mentioned this can result in an infinite loop if you change the text there.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If the size of the label is not to depend upon its contents, then it must depend upon something else, presumably external constraints. So the size is known absolutely, and now you know which text to insert (which won't change the size). Or, if auto layout gives you trouble, take the label out of the control of auto layout altogether. — However, perhaps the easiest solution is not to use UILabel; it's easy to create a UIView that draws a string, and now you're in total control (whereas UILabel, as you've discovered, does some layout trickery).

Comment: The problem is similar to how apple adds ellipses or shrinks the font when the text is too long.  Instead of ellipses I would just replace the entire text.  I was thinking of maybe making some view with two labels.  `preferred` would have low horizontal compression resistance, and `alternate` would have high resistance.  Then I could pin each of them to the edges using autolayout.  During `layoutSubviews` I would hide/show as appropriate based on the actual frame.  I was hoping to just subclass UILabel directly though.

Comment: "The problem is similar to how apple adds ellipses or shrinks the font when the text is too long" Well, we actually know how they do that. You could do it the same way. In that case you'd need to use, again, not a UILabel, but a custom view, and implement the Text Kit "stack" (because the work is done during layout).